# Change protected value in object (PHP)

Tags: php, object, visibility

When I do a var_dump of the array `$mailer` I get:

```
object(Fooman_EmailAttachments_Model_Core_Email_Template_Mailer)#352 (8) {
["_emailInfos":protected]=>
array(3) {
[0]=>
object(Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info)#409 (11) {
["_bccNames":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
["_bccEmails":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
["_toNames":protected]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(13) "My Name"
}
["_toEmails":protected]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(17) "justatest@test.com"
}
["_data":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
["_hasDataChanges":protected]=>
bool(false)
["_origData":protected]=>
NULL
["_idFieldName":protected]=>
NULL
["_isDeleted":protected]=>
bool(false)
["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=>
array(0) {
}
}
```

I would like to edit the `_toEmails` but how do I access and edit it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: You can't do this directly. I don't know the library you are using, but it *may* have a setter method to change this value, something like `$object->setToEmails`

Comment: It's not an array it's an object. Please show us the code of the class `Fooman_EmailAttachments_Model_Core_Email_Template_Mailer` propably there is a setter method for this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the really simple example (with no error checking) of how you could do this with the `ReflectionClass`:

```
function setProtectedProperty($obj, $property, $value) {
  $reflection = new ReflectionClass($obj);
  $property = $reflection->getProperty($property);
  $property->setAccessible(true);
  return $property->setValue($obj, $value);
}

setProtectedProperty($mailer, '_toEmails', ['foo@bar.com']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have to tell you that there's probably a reason why this has been hidden, and there most likely is a way to set this without accessing it directly (as others have made sure to tell you), however you can extend the class and add your own method that sets it:

```
<?php
    class Foo {
        protected $_destroyDatabase = false;
    }

    class Bar extends Foo {
        public function SetDestroyDatabase($destroyDatabase) {
            $this->_destroyDatabase = $destroyDatabase;
        }
    }

    $foo = new Foo();
    $foo->_destroyDatabase = true; //Fatal error
    var_dump($foo);
    /*
        object(Foo)#1 (1) {
          ["_destroyDatabase:protected"]=>
          bool(false)
        }
    */

    $bar = new Bar();
    $bar->SetDestroyDatabase(true); //Success
    var_dump($bar);
    /*
        object(Bar)#2 (1) {
          ["_destroyDatabase:protected"]=>
          bool(true)
        }
    */
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/yNgefML8)

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for class `Fooman_EmailAttachments_Model_Core_Email_Template_Mailer`. There ought to be a *method* you can call to edit the information,
something like `$mailer->setEmails('foo')`. If there isn't then the data isn't meant to be modified.